# PHP sleep() function killing script after some time

Tags: php

I am experiencing a problem when using sleep() function in php for a long period of time, if i test the following code all runs perfectly:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$i = 0;

while($i < 10) {

    echo $i.'<br />';

    if($i == 5){        
        echo 'sleeping 5 secs<br />';
        sleep(5);   
        echo 'waking up<br />';
    }

    $i++;
}

?>

*****OUTPUT****

0
1
2
3
4
5
sleeping 5 secs
waking up
6
7
8
9

*****OUTPUT****
```

It sleeps 5 seconds and after that the "waking up" is echoed without problems, but, if I raise the amount of seconds the script is sleeping to lets say 15 minutes the output is the following:

```
*****OUTPUT****

0
1
2
3
4
5
sleeping 900 secs //(15 mins)

*****OUTPUT****
```

The script appears to be killed after 15 minutes of sleeping!!, what could be causing this? note that I set the max_execution_time flag to infinite with set_time_limit(0); at the top of the script.

I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I'm curious, why would you sleep a script for 15 minutes?

Comment: Yeah, the same question

Comment: Is this CLI or browser based?

Answer (score 1):

Even the webserver (Apache, IIS, ...) has a timeout setting, try to check your many has 300sec as default).

Moreover be carefull about set_time_limit. From the manual: 'This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.'

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual:

> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero.
>   In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25
>   seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is
>   made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Try with:

```
set_time_limit(900);
```

Doing `set_time_limit(0);` is not recommended because your web server might  impose an HTTP timeout which is usually around 5 minutes.